# nested fetch api react native giving unpredictable response for custom operation

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

hi i am trying to fill array with custom data using multiple apis in react native but unable to do so as nested fetch api giving unpredicatable result my final array is always empty .

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance
below is my code please tell what i am doing wrong here..

```
fetchSubcategories(category_id){



    var url=GLOBAL.BASE_URL+'/categories?filter[where][categoryId]='+GLOBAL.CATEGORY_ID+'&filter[where][category_type]=subcategory&filter[order]=name ASC';

    const set = [];
    const subcategoriesArray=[];

      fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {

          for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
                  set.push(responseData[i]);
          }
          console.log('response subcategories : '+JSON.stringify(set,null,2));


        })
        .then(()=>{

                  for(var j=0;j<set.length;j++){

                      var name=set[j].name;
                      var id=set[j].id;


                     fetch(url)
                        .then((response) => response.json())
                        .then((responseData) => {

                          var subcategory={
                            name:name,
                            id:id,
                            products:[]
                          }

                          subcategoriesArray.push(subcategory);

                        }).done()




                  }

        })
        .done()


        console.log('final custom josn array : '+JSON.stringify(subcategoriesArray,null,2));



}
```

Note : urls used above giving the proper result on my end the only thing is final subcategoriesArray should be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` is "asynchronous", so your `console.log` is probably running before the request has actually finished, but the array is actually being populated.

To test: try moving your `console.log` to just after `subcategoriesArray.push(subcategory);`

You should see it log out the array for each set, but at least you can see it is actually being populated.

You could wrap the function in a `Promise` so you can get the array after it has been async populated:

```js
fetchSubcategories(category_id){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // <- add this

        var url=GLOBAL.BASE_URL+'/categories?filter[where][categoryId]='+GLOBAL.CATEGORY_ID+'&filter[where][category_type]=subcategory&filter[order]=name ASC';

        const set = [];
        const subcategoriesArray=[];

        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {

                for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
                    set.push(responseData[i]);
                }

                console.log('response subcategories : '+JSON.stringify(set,null,2));

            })
            .then(()=>{

                for(var j=0;j<set.length;j++){

                    var name=set[j].name;
                    var id=set[j].id;

                    fetch(url)
                        .then((response) => response.json())
                        .then((responseData) => {

                            var subcategory={
                                name:name,
                                id:id,
                                products:[]
                            }

                            subcategoriesArray.push(subcategory);

                            if(j == set.length-1) { // <- add this block 

                                resolve(subcategoriesArray);

                            }

                        }).done();

                }

            }).done()

    });  // <- completes promise block

}
```

You can then use it like this:

```js
fetchSubcategories(category_id).then((subCatArray) => {
    console.log('final custom join array', subCatArray);
});
```

Hope this helps! :)